# Get the data from database for second column of the table

Tags: c#, jquery

I am creating a table in which first column is column header and second column will be column data. Now I don't know is that possible to get data either via c# or javascript. Below is the example

```
<html> 
<body> 
<h1>Small Bakery Products</h1> 
<table border="1" width="100%"> 
<tr>
<td>Id</td> 
<td>@data.id</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td> 
<td>@data.Name</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description</td> 
<td>@data.Description</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Price</td> 
<td>@data.Price</td> 
</tr>
</table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Both are possible. Either you can bind the data from server using the razor syntax if you are working with MVC or you can make an ajax call to retrieve the entities and loop through it to generate the above pattern

Comment: @JithinJoy do you have any reference through which I can understand how to do it?

Comment: [hope this help](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sampleData = [{"Id":"1000", "Name":"Sample Name 1", "Description":"sample description 1"},
                  {"Id":"1001", "Name":"Sample Name 2", "Description":"sample description 2"},
                  {"Id":"1002", "Name":"Sample Name 3", "Description":"sample description 3"}];


$(document).ready(function(){

var table = $('<table border="1"></table>');
  for(var i = 0;i<sampleData.length;i++){
    
  var item = sampleData[i];
    
    table.append('<tr><td>Id</td><td>'+item.Id+'</td><tr>');
    table.append('<tr><td>Name</td><td>'+item.Name+'</td><tr>');
    table.append('<tr><td>Description</td><td>'+item.Description+'</td><tr>');
  }
  
  $('#container').append(table);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datatable plugin to populate your table.

look at below example.

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Now initialize your table using datatable.

for that you need some style and script references like.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" ></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "info": true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],
        "ajax":{
            "url": "@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))/Home/AjaxGetJsonData",
            "type": "GET"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Name", "orderable" : true },
            { "data": "Position", "orderable": false },
            { "data": "Office", "orderable": true }
        ],
        "order": [[0, "asc"]]
    });
});
```

now you are wondering that from where the data comes.
but look at this statement.

```
"ajax":{
        "url": "@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))/Home/AjaxGetJsonData",
        "type": "GET"
    },
```

These ajax call will get data from method **Home/AjaxGetJsonData**.

Here you have not mention which framework you are using, so i assume that you are using MVC, and below is the code for getting data from back end.

```
public JsonResult AjaxGetJsonData()
    {
        Database db = new Database();

        var userList = db.YourTable.Select(m => new
        {
            m.Name,
            m.Position,
            m.Office
        });

        return Json(new
        {
            data = userList
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

so what actually you are doing,

- create table with only headers.
- then initialize datatable
- call to action called AjaxGetJsonData(), which returns required jsondata.
- and at last your table is populated.

below are the site that may be usefull to check examples and syntax.

https://datatables.net/

still you are facing any issue, then just comment it below my answer..